# Implementing Private chat with Windows Forms and asp.net signar

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i done the winform client and web client and winform sever by reffering the following links.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

but it is implemented in group chat but i want it as private chat.

Thankas in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on this project.

It's a one to one chat: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room

The relevant function for you :

```
public void SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message)
{  
   string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;
   var toUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId) ;
   var fromUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);

   if (toUser != null && fromUser!=null)
   {
       // send to
       Clients.Client(toUserId).sendPrivateMessage(fromUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);

       // send to caller user
       Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(toUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);
   }

}
```

Comment: hi @Quentin Roger,it is  the web application,but i want it in windows forms.now i am on working on the same ,by taking code project references,but so many fuctions are there ,i confused at how to use in             windowsforms.

Comment: The server code is exactly the same, the only thing you have to do is to create child windows to chat with a particular user.

Comment: i am  struggled at that please send me any references for doing that.

Comment: hi @Quentin Roger,i am almost done but i am stopped at cretaion of new window form  for providing the private chat.can u send the references for doing that

Comment: hi, @Quentin Roger,please suggest me.